# How do I power a LCD Backlight inverter (got from a disasembled LCD screen)

Tags: connector, lcd, wiring, inverter

I have two LCD Backlight Inverters lying around here and I want them to powerup without using any laptop part / motherboards.

I want to power it by using a simple power source, I have both AC and DC transformers available in the 5V to 24V range.

[image]

Here are more pictures of the CCFL's I got: http://gz.pxf24.pl/inverter.html

Thanks in advance for your time, effort and help!

If anyone knows how to do the wiring/connecting I will be really happy.

---

Edit:

Here are 2 HQ photos:

[image: side 1]
[Click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9ArL.jpg)

[image: side 2]
[Click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Egt.jpg)

---

Finally got it working thanks to the answer below, here is a picture:

[image]

If you want to connect it acording to the picture in the answer, you need to look at the BACK of the inverter and connect the following together:

1,2,6 to + , all others to -, take an adapter which is exactly 4.5 volts DC.

UPDATE 2:

I experimented a bit and only 2 needs to be connected to the + and 4,5 need to be connected to - and that's enough to get this running!

However no joy for the other inverter, maybe it's broken.

Comment: The socket at the right will be the input connector, but without some (properly focused) closeup pics (need to be able to see the traces) it's not really possible to say what to connect to where. The right hand 3rd of the PCB (back/front) is the main bit of interest. The wire colours may give a clue, or what they were connected to on the motherboard (if you still have it)

Comment: Also be careful with those things the voltage they produce is really high and you can zap yourself just getting close to it.  Not that that's happened to me...  Oh and I've seen someone short one through an ESD mat too.

Comment: I will try to take some 8MP pictures with my fathers camera. It makes sharp photos ^.^ just need to find the batteries for it XD

Comment: Also, there is no "universal" wiring? Like for the  second inverter which has colored wires?

Comment: The trick with camera is not 8MP but get enough light and not to0 close so it can focus. Then you can compress it with i_view down to 100KB and still be 8MP

Comment: well i need to find some batteries first, eh :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the find the specs for that particular P/N. They are not universal.
You can buy CFL tubes from Digikey for $5 or so. 1.5mm or 2mm probably by x mm long.

For example here is a [T-Y interface spec.](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/indexer.php?file=DSA0035425.pdf&dir=Datasheet-02&keywords=cfl%20inverter%20%20circuit) click image to open PDF file.

That looks like this.
[image]

Comment: AMBIT REV. 4 T27.002.C.00 83M120011-00 is the model number and the other one has TOKIN 0456492RGAJ and I can't seem to find the right cirtcuit for it..

Comment: I believe Tokin stopped making them but make all the piezo and magnetic parts. Can you guess by matching up tracks and voltage & polarity of caps? Bright control may be either PWM or analog or both.

Comment: If I had a measure device here, my last one broke, I'll try the circuit above, in the worst case it'll damage the inverters :p

Comment: maybe you can find a cheap DMM nearby like this one. Can't work without tools. http://www.harborfreight.com/7-function-multimeter-98025.html

Comment: let there be light

Answer (score 1):

Find and check the fuse on the dead inverter.  I never found a bad inverter that wasn't the fuse.